# How do I re-activate PulseAudio? (followed guide on skype.com)

Tags: pulseaudio, skype

I disabled PulseAudio to be able to use my microphone for Skype, and now the volume controls don't work, which I understand, is a common problem.

I read that somebody fixed their Skype microphone by going to `system setting > multimedia > phonon > audio recording > prefer webcam microphone`.

I'd like to try that, but I think I need to enable PulseAudio again. How do I do that?

I used the following guide on Skype's support pages to disable PulseAudio: [Can I change the sound system used by Skype for Linux?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10964/can-i-change-the-sound-system-used-by-skype-for-linux?frompage=search&fromSearchFirstPage=false&q=microphone%20linux)

Comment: I tried installing Pulse Audio from the Ubuntu Software Center and it did install, but now when I try to click on the Volume Control, it says: Fatal Error: Unable to connect to PulseAudio:OK. so I can't even access Pulse Audio, and it's not even visible in the System Monitor....

Comment: How did you disable pulse audio?. Did you remove that from your system?

Comment: I disabled it according to Skype's suggestions here https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10964/Can-I-change-the-sound-system-used-by-Skype-for-Linux?frompage=search&q=microphone+linux&fromSearchFirstPage=false and then set up ALSA

Answer (score 1):

## Re-enabling PulseAudio autospawn

What you did by following the guide, was to prevent PulseAudio to start automatically when you login to your account. If that worked for you, than changing `autospawn=no` to `autospawn=yes` should also work. I would prefer doing this from the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by running the following command:

```
sed -i 's/autospawn=no/autospawn=yes/g' ~/.pulse/client.conf
```

Now you just need to reboot or logout and login to let the changes take effect.

## Configure Skype

The guide you followed didn't setup ALSA, but configured some sound devices to specifically use ALSA devices instead of the default device or something else. So, going to `Main Menu > Options > Sound Devices` and revert the settings back to default will get you back to the starting point.

### Are you using KDE/Kubuntu or Unity/Ubuntu?

I want to point out that **Phonon** is a component from the KDE desktop. If you are not using KDE/Kubuntu, then installing KDE might not be the straightest solution to fix your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-enable the pulseaudio by deleting the folder `.pulse` and the file `.pulse-cookie` in your home directory. Then logging out and login again.

#### Enable viewing hidden files:

If you are using Dolphin file manager of Kubuntu, Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to see hidden files and folder.

In Nautilus, *(If you are using default Ubuntu)* The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

or just do this on a terminal window

```
pulseaudio -k
```

or

```
killall pulseaudio
```

and then

```
pulseaudio --check
```

to check if any instances are running

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Skype docs recommend using Pulsaudio:
[Link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10964/how-do-i-adjust-the-sound-settings-on-my-computer-and-in-skype-for-linux?intcmp=blogs-_-generic-click-_-skype-4-3-for-linux)

By default, pusleaudio is not started, I put in Startup applications.